# In-App Purchase check get notification based on renewing

Tags: in-app-purchase

I am implementing In-App purchases on iOS once I have done a subscription which is of type auto renewal. I will get the below response. I need a notification when user cancel the subscription from settings page

Here is the response what i get if the product is

```
"pending_renewal_info":[
{"auto_renew_product_id":"com.month", 
"original_transaction_id":"1000000*********", 
"product_id":"com.month", "auto_renew_status":"1"}, 
{"expiration_intent":"1", 
"auto_renew_product_id":"com.annualplan", 
"original_transaction_id":"1000000*********", "is_in_billing_retry_period":"0", 
"product_id":"com.annualplan", "auto_renew_status":"1"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't clearly understand your question. Did you set notification status url?
Make sure your url is set in your app's page in App Store Connect. Then you should listen for `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREF` notification in your server.

Please specify what exactly your problem is. We have implemented a notification when user cancels the subscription from settings page. I can recommend reading this article from our blog: https://blog.apphud.com/subscriptions-notifications/

Comment: I was expecting this only Ty